# My Visual Studio can't find the Windows SDK 10.0.16299

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

[image]
Our work is on the 10.0.16299 version. Previously, it worked well.
Today, I have to update my VS. After the upgrade, there are 2 more other versions of Windows SDK - 10.1.15063, 10.1.17134.
When I compile my old projects, all they failed. Because the compiler can't find the SDK 10.0.16299.

[image]
[image]

It only recognizes the other new-installed versons. Even after I repaired the 10.0.16299, the VS still couldn't recognize the recognizes 10.0.16299.

How do I do to make the VS recognize the 10.0.16299?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "*Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → Build and Run*" and set both verbosity properties to Diagnostic and launch build. In the output looking for **WindowsSdkDir**.

Inside this folder go to "*DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP*" and check what version of WSDK was choosed in project and what version you have in specified **WindowsSdkDir** \ ... \ UAP folder

Comment: I had to search for "WindowsSdkPath" instead of "WindowsSdkDir".The target version is 18362 but error is Could not find SDK "WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.16299.0". I upgraded the .NET framework from v4.6 to v4.8.

Comment: To answer to myself the project file has "<SDKReference Include="WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.16299.0">". In another project file had invalid Windows version reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd". I will update them manually.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Use the Visual Studio Installer to reinstall the sdk version.