# Visual Studio 2022 #include Directory does not start at the source file

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

After installing DirectX SDK June 2010, all of my #include's are now not found since it is searching for files inside of that SDK.

When I write #include "file.h", I expect to include the file that is in the same directory as the source file, visual studio, instead searches for file.h in the directory of DirectX sdk instead of the source file directory

Here is an image to help you understand:
[image]

I've tried to reinstall visual C++ and reset project parameters in VC++ tab, but it did not help

Comment: When I write #include "file.h", I expect to include the file that is in the same directory as the source file, visual studio, instead searches for file.h in the directory of DirectX sdk instead of the source file directory

Comment: Interesting, I've not had that (mis)behavior with Visual Studio 2022.  I'd check the include paths and include path order (but that's just a guess).

Comment: When **I** write `#include "file.h"`, I expect that the compiler uses the search paths that I supplied to it.  Some compilers use an option `-I` (capital i), while others may have a configuration window instead.

Comment: You shouldn't use the legacy DirectX SDK 2010 but use the Windows SDK that comes with Visual Studio 2022 https://stackoverflow.com/a/51375132/403671

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** **Don't use the legacy DirectX SDK.** The modern Windows SDKs that come with Visual Studio dating back to VS 2012 *already includes* everything you need including the HLSL compiler, Direct3D headers & libraries, etc.

> If you want to make use of legacy D3DX9, D3DX10, and/or D3DX11 in your project, use the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX/9.29.952.3) instead.

You *can* use the legacy DirectX SDK, but you have to manually add the proper INCLUDE/LIB paths to the **VC++ Directories** settings even back in Visual Studio 2010. The key issue is that many of the headers the legacy DirectX SDK are *OLDER* than the system headers in the modern Windows SDK, so you have be careful about search order and apply some hacks depending on what of the old content you are using. All the details for this are on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-). The simpler answer is don't use it at all.

For lots and lots of background and detail, see these blog posts:

https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2021-edition/

https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/

https://walbourn.github.io/the-zombie-directx-sdk/

https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/

https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdk-tools-catalog/

https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdk-samples-catalog/